# Whole website redirects to wrong url, what could be causing this?

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently moved one of my old sites to a new domain, because the old domain expired.
Now on the new domain, I get an issue that the root URL seems to be: `newdomain.com/newdomain/`
So whenever I go to wp-admin, it redirects to `newdomain.com/newdomain/wp-login.php`.
If I try to login, on `newdomain.com/login.php`, it redirects to `newdomain.com/newdomain/login.php`.
I tried deactiving plugins/themes. And this problem persists.
I updated the URL correctly in the database (siteurl and home)
Has anyone ran into this situation? What could be causing this?

Comment: website in question if anyone is keen to take a look: https://topvacuumsealers.com/

Comment: I'm sure there's search / replace or similar plugin for this purpose.

Comment: it doesn't do any good for the website, because I cannot access the wp-admin @ITgoldman

Comment: Do you have a database back up?

Comment: Then you can use this script to replace in db. https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/. Also please check `.htaccess` file for anomilies

Comment: .htaccess was breaking the site on the new domain, so I removed it.
How can I make use of it to help troubleshoot? I really have no clue what's causing this.
Domain is linked above btw
`php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: @user3783243 i do have a backup of the database. I just migrated the website to the new domain

Comment: You could restore DB, change your host file so the new domain resolves as the old, fix the domain name in db, then should be able to connect. Looks like currently you have domain name double in DB references.

Comment: **Use a migration plugin!** Moving a site from one hostname to another is an intricate task, and the available plugins do it right.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set any redirection settings on your server, check `.htaccess` or `nginx` configuration file. For apache webservice, your `.htaccess` should be like below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Tried this script, it didn't fix my issue unfortunately. Do you believe this to be from the server end? I've ran out of solution, no idea what may be causing this